# HyperTalk-like language for use with the CLR

Tags: .net, clr, hypertalk

I was always a big fan of [HyperTalk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperTalk) back in the days of Stacks in HyperCard.  Are there any HyperTalk-like languages available for use with Visual Studio and the CLR?  The benefits of using natural language syntax (e.g. Get the third line of text in the textbox named Comments) and strong-typing would be magnificant.  The real goal is to create something extremely Business Analyst friendly, since even VB.NET can be daunting.

Comment: That's actually not that bad an idea, especially given that example line. Unfortunately, there are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting concept. I wonder if the recent interest in [Domain-specific Languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_specific_language) (DSLs) is the modern equivalent.

You might check out

- [Meta Programming System](http://www.jetbrains.com/mps/index.html)
- [Oslo and Textual DSLs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd441702.aspx)
- [Windows PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) (relatively easy to write custom cmdlets)
- [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) (supports targeting .NET)
- [Boo](http://boo.codehaus.org/) (allegedly easy to extend, but this was not my experience)

Comment: These are some interesting links; some of which I've encountered in the past.  Since I can't really find exactly what I'm looking for it may be time to launch a CodePlex project of my own to fill the void.

Comment: @Nissan Fan: Thanks! If you do, please post the info as an answer - that would be interesting and potentially very useful!